# how to find a longest monotonous decrease subsequence in an array?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic

OK, Here is my problem:

---

Given an array, such as {9, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2}, its longest monotonous decrease subsequence is {9, 5, 4, 3, 2}, where each element is in the same order as in original array. For simplicity, we assume the elements in subsequence are all different.

---

I have thought about it for a whole day and can't get a solution... If you have some good advises, please share with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dynamic programming problem. The idea is to evaluate every possible subsequence combination and store sub problem results in an array so you don't need to compute them twice.

```
public class LDS {

    /*
      For each item in the array, get the longest
      decreasing subsequence to that item.

      return the max subsequence to that item, adding
      1 for the item itself.

      In both calculate and longestToN, subproblem results  are stored and reused to 
      avoid duplicate computation.
    */
    public int calculate(int []arr) {
        int []table = new int[arr.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            table[i] = -1;
        }

        int m = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < arr.length; ++n) {

            if (table[n] == -1) {//Memoize
                table[n] = longestToN(n, arr, table);
            }

            m = Math.max(m, longestToN(n, arr, table));
        }
        return m + 1;
    }

    /*
      Recursively finds the longest decreasing subsequence in array up until arr[n] inclusive.
    */
    private int longestToN(int n, int []arr, int []table) {
        int m = 0;
        for (int i = n; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[n]) {

                if (table[i] == -1) {//Memoize
                    table[i] = longestToN(i, arr, table);
                }

                m = Math.max(m, 1 + table[i]);
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

To run the code:

```
    LDS lds = new LDS();

    int []arr = {9, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2};
    int ret = lds.calculate(arr);

    System.out.println("Longest decreasing subsequence is " + ret);
```

Running the code on your example input calculates 5. I recommend a book called the algorithm design manual for a better understanding of dynamic programming. The author is a professor and posts lectures from his algorithms online @ http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/373/.

Comment: Thk u Ryan, the book you recommended is very great!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to rearrange the sequence into a sequence of trees; each item in the original sequence becomes a node in one of the trees.  Its parent is defined to be the first preceding item that is greater.  Then the longest subsequence is the longest tree branch, which you can compute easily by walking all the trees (or keep track as they are being constructed).  I don't think there is a more efficient way but that's just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a copy of the array, and sort it in descending order
2. Find the longest common subsequence of the two arrays, using dynamic programming techniques

Answer (score 0):

Recursion for Solving the problem

`L(j) = max(1+ L(i)) where i A[j]

L(j) : Longest Decreasing Subsequence until jth index of the array`

You can use Dynamic Programming to reduce the Time Complexity of the Solution.